# Yii set date default timezone error

Tags: php, yii

After creating new webapp with its name. I get this error now.

**PHP warning**

`date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.`

After got this result I wrote this to config array:

```
'timeZone' => 'Asia/Tehran',
```

and to index.php:

```
Yii::app()->setTimeZone("UTC");
```

But that does not change anything and the problem remains unsolved.

My default system date is :

```
Tue Dec 31 14:11:49 IRST 2013
```

php.ini :

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
;date.timezone =

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333

; http://php.net/date.sunset-zenith
;date.sunset_zenith = 90.583333
```

Comment: Why aren't you setting it in php.ini, in the date.timezone entry, as the error message suggests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use this if you do not want to touch your php.ini file

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Tehran");
```

OR

```
ini_set('date.timezone','Asia/Tehran');
```

**Update**
You can also use

```
ini_alter('date.timezone','Asia/Tehran');
```

But do not forget to call it before calling any date function.

Comment: after set that i get this error in this link now : `http://localhost/yii/ts/index.php?r=message`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the error you should set the `date.timezone` in PHP ini :

```
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = Asia/Tehran
```

Note that in the ini file `;` is a comment so this has been removed from the date.timezone line.

Answer (score 1):

I Would go for setting Global setting in php.ini file

`date.timezone` in php.ini can fix this globally.

Set all attributes there only and then restart  http service

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, set the timezone in `php.ini`: `date.timezone = Asia/Tehran`

And don't forget to restart your webserver afterwards. ;-)